# Azure Ad B2C : how to disable continue button. When email is not already registered for password reset

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I was expecting that if email id is not registered during the PasswordReset flow.
Custom policy would disable the continue button. But that is not how the current behaviour is. User is not been taken through right journey, He will be allowed to click again the "continue" button.

Is there a way to disable continue button if email address does not exist?

[image]

Comment: Maybe we don't need to disable it, because we can actually press the continue button only three times if it doesn't work.

Comment: The link highlights a different issue. After we know that the user is not registered and prompted with the error message."Continue" button should be disabled, and only the "Change-email" button should be highlighted.

Comment: It seems to be it's by design please raise the [uservoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) regarding the request

Answer (score 3):

There are two parts here.

1. "Continue" button appears by default and it's greyed when it's not needed.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow
2. "Continue" button could be removed with a custom JavaScript https://github.com/stevenxzhou/B2C-Samples/blob/master/Email-Verification-Automatic-Redirect.js

Comment: Apparently, the behavior of the continue button in the forgot password case changed from page layout version 2.1.6 (disabled when field is empty) to 2.1.7+ (never disabled). No idea why though...

Answer (score 0):

As of now, the continue button does not depend on the email field. Continue is always enable state by design. As you are interested in disabling the continue button-based valid email address provided please raise the [uservoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) regarding the request